# different ports in server test during postman message

Tags: api

we create an external URL having port 80 to listen from internal server URL have port 443.
the client using the external URL to start postman searching in an application in internal server.

there is an error showed
'500 internal server error'

https://mawidtsthis.moh.gov.sa  port 443 (outside client using external URL https://mawid.kfsh.med.sa port 80 to access the internal URL)
https://fhir-kfsh-mcctst-web.kfsh.med.sa/ internal server URL port 443

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z63O2.jpg)

what is the wrong? I need assistance

Comment: What does the internal server error say? Do all of the URLs have this error?

Comment: As locally no error appear only the external url

Comment: Can you the full text of the error message? Do you see the error in your web server access logs?

Comment: ''This result is being rendered in HTML for easy viewing. You may access this content as Raw JSON or Raw XML, or view this content in HTML JSON or HTML XML.
HTTP 200 OK''
but no body response